# RxJs merge observables emitting at different times

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular language service where I need to initialize a language$ variable according to specific priority: from a Provider (if given), from localStorage (if key given), or from static value (fallback).

If the user selects a language from the UI, this must update the service language$ variable.

With the current implementation, just the first value of the `merge` operator is taken. 
For example, at startup, the language$ is correctly set if given by the provider. However, when the `languageSubject$` emits a value, this is not taken,  but the provider value is always returned.

My goal would be to provide an initial language (given by the provider or fallback language) and then update it as the `languageSubject$` emits.

Here is the service:

```
language$: Language;

constructor() {
    const window = (document as Document)?.defaultView;
    this.navigator = window?.navigator;
    this.localStorage = window?.localStorage;

    this.language$ = this.initializeLanguage();
}

private initializeLanguage(): Observable<Language> {
   const initialLanguage = 'it';

   const languageFromUserInput$ = this.languageSubject$.asObservable();

   return merge(this.getLanguageFromLanguageProvider(), languageFromUserInput$)
         .pipe(
               map(lang => lang ?? initialLanguage
               ),
               shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
            );
    }

// Custom provider returning a language (eg. 'fr')
private getLanguageFromLanguageProvider() {
    if (!this.languageProvider) {
        return of(undefined);
    }

    return this.languageProvider.getLanguage()
        .pipe(
              catchError(() => of(undefined))
             );
}
```

Comment: What you have seens fine so the problem is going to be somewhere else

Comment: Why are you using shareReplay()? Using an Observable from a Subject is already enough?

Comment: The returned observable is subscribed in different parts, we want to share the same observable.